# setInterval interfering with hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently implemented a loading image and noticed that ever 10 seconds, that the loading image appears for a split second then disappears again. I've traced it to this code. When I comment this out, the loading image never appears until it is supposed to. I'm using the setInterval code globally so is there something that I can do to get these two things working nicely together?

I want to stop the loading image from appearing for a brief second.

```
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function() {
      ....
    }, 10000
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you ask, if you mean execute it only once then change the code to setTimeout instead:

```
var auto_refresh = window.setTimeout(
    function() {
      ....
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: I need a div updated every 10 seconds. This won't work, will it?

Comment: @jim you said "loading image appears for a split second then disappears again" - what is the **desired** situation? I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: The problem is that with setInterval, my loading div content briefly appears then disappears. The image shows in unison with the interval value which in my case is 10 seconds. Obviously, the desired result would be to hide my div content until the user does something like click a link or whatever.

Comment: Shadow, I'm not sure why but the `window` part you added to my code fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @jim that's really weird... that `window` part is optional just out of habit - unless you have your own `setInterval` defined somewhere. Anyway glad I helped, even indirectly. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the event to be triggered periodically, you should look at [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead. It only fires once.

```
  var auto_refresh = setTimeout(
    function() {
      ....
    }, 10000
  );
```

Comment: Dude you really need to explain the problem in more detail. Please update the question.